# Problem with insert and psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm a newbie in Python and psycopg2 and have problems with a simple insert.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla
(
codigo integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('dato_codigo_seq'::regclass),
informacion character(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT dato_pkey PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
)
```

The field `codigo` is a serial.

When I do the sentence:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla informacion) VALUES (%s)",("abcdef"))
```

PostgreSQL throws an exception.

I must do

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla (codigo,informacion) VALUES (nextval(%s),%s)",
            ("dato_codigo_seq","abcdef"))
```

where `dato_codigo_seq` is the sequence to the field `codigo`.

My question isL Can I do a sentence like

`insert into tabla(informacion)values('asdsa')`

and let PostgreSQL handle the treatment of the serial field?

I can do this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla informacion) VALUES ("+valor+")")"
```

but that sentence can be used to attack with a SQL injection.

That's all.  Thanks for reading my question, and sorry for my bad english (I speak Spanish).

Comment: having a similar problem. However, the '''cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla informacion) VALUES ("+valor+")")"''' type line doesn't save in the database. It just increments my db serial.

Answer (score 4):

```
cursor.execute("""insert into tabla (informacion) VALUES (%s);""",(asdas,))
```

that is the solution

Comment: to be more explicit, the second argument of execute() must be a tuple, and in Python the trailing comma is mandatory for 1-item tuples.

Answer (score 0):

in your example :

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabla informacion) VALUES (%s)",("abcdef",))
```